# tap or long press at time_planner to add new task in flutter

Tags: flutter, tap, gesturedetector, long-press

I added time_planner into my flutter project ('package:time_planner/time_planner.dart';
) . Yes, it is working properly in my application.

But I just wanted to know how can I create a new task for a hour/minute by long pressing or tapping on that empty cell to trigger adding a new task.

I can add a new task from pressing a separate button and entering (or picking from a time picker tool) the time (hour-minute) values.

Here is the code I used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_planner/time_planner.dart';

class timeselect extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_timeselectState createState() => _timeselectState(); 
}

class _timeselectState extends State<timeselect> {

DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

 Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
 final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(2022, 8),
    lastDate: DateTime(2024));
 if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
  setState(() {
    selectedDate = picked;
  });
 }
 }

void _addTask(BuildContext context)
{
  setState(() {
    TimePlannerTask(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 117, 117),
      dateTime: TimePlannerDateTime(
          day: 11,
          hour: 18,
          minutes: 35,),
      minutesDuration: 45,
      daysDuration: 1,
      onTap: () {

      },
      child: Text(
        'this is a demo',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[350], fontSize: 12),
      ),
    );
    });
   }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,

body: SingleChildScrollView(
padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 11),
 child:  Column (
 children: [

ElevatedButton(
child: const Text('Today''s Timetable...'),

onPressed: () {
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    List<TimePlannerTask> tasks = [
      TimePlannerTask(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 144, 0, 255),
        dateTime: TimePlannerDateTime(day: 0, hour: 09, minutes: 15),
        minutesDuration: 50,
        onTap: () {},
        child: const Text(
          'sample text here',
          style: TextStyle(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255), fontSize: 12),
        ),),),];

    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8, 
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 600, 
              child: TimePlanner(
                style: TimePlannerStyle(
                                    cellHeight: 60,
                                    cellWidth: 291,
                                    dividerColor: Colors.white,
                                    showScrollBar: true,
                                    horizontalTaskPadding: 1,
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              
                currentTimeAnimation: true,
                startHour: 8,
                endHour: 20,
                headers: const [
                  TimePlannerTitle(                        
                    date: "3/10/2023",
                    title: "sunday",                        
                  ),
                ],
                tasks: tasks,
                
              ),
            ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
       );
     },
   );
  },
  ),
 ]
 ),
 )
 );
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried?

Comment: because of the character limit of this comment box, I am adding the code into the question code.